# pyenv global x.x.x does not update the python version on linux

Tags: python, pyenv

I have *pyenv* installed and have downloaded python versions 3.6.15 and 3.7.12. When I run

```
pyenv global 3.7.12
python -V
```

the output is: **Python 3.10.2**

*pyenv versions* gives the output

```
system
3.6.15
* 3.7.12 (set by /home/frege/.pyenv/version)
```

**$ echo $PYENV_ROOT**: /home/frege/.pyenv

**$ which python**: /user/bin/python

**$ type python**: python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)

I have the following in my *.bashrc*

```
export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I have restarted my terminal and $PATH contains

```
/home/frege/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:
/home/frege/.pyenv/bin:
...
/usr/bin:
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you do `which python` and `type python`?

Comment: You might be missing `export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"`.

Comment: It's actually nice to see you're running an OS that uses a very recent version of Python ;-). But that's besides the point.

Comment: There might be some additional configuration to do in `.bashrc` or the like. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout , then point 2., then the "For Bash" section; which itself has three separate sections, depending on your setup (and that excludes the virtualenv setup).

Comment: Note that for me (OSX though), I have `$HOME/.pyenv/shims` in my `$PATH` as well; I don't see it listed in the block where you show some parts of your `$PATH`. This might be what `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` takes care of. (It sures looks like that, when I do `pyenv init --path`.) So that might be missing.

Comment: export PATH="/home/frege/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}" fixes it, but pyenv init --path does not update my PATH - do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: As per the linked documentation, the full line to add to your source file would be `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks - that's all working, but now python global system does not revert back to the system python - any ideas?

Comment: Please ignore last comment - I forgot about .python-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that getting pyenv and virtualenvs to work together can be problematic. I came from virtualenvwrapper which makes working on virtual envs  simple and I found pyenv a bit of a culture shock.

I have finally got my workflow sorted and I thought I would post it here as it might help someone. My OS is Manjaro.

I installed pyenv:

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

The following was added to .bashrc:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:${PATH}"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy
```

(I have not seen the line *export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:${PATH}"* in many explanations, but it is critical in mine.)

To invoke a *global* version of python:

```
pyenv shell <version>
```

or

```
pyenv shell system
```

To create a virtual env:

```
pyenv virtualenv <version> <env name>
```

To activate the virtual environment:

```
pyenv activate <env name>
```

To deactivate the virtual environment:

```
source deactivate
```